# Get ascending order of numbers in array in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a Numpy array with some numbers and I would like to get order the items ascending order.

For example, I have a list:

`[4, 25, 100, 4, 50]`

And I would like to use a function to get this:

`[1, 2, 4, 1, 3]`

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Weirdly, you used exactly the same array as I did... Thanks.

Comment: @jpp This assumes 1-based offset, so we simply need to add `1` to the linked Q&A's accepted answer. To me, that's a minimal extension and hence a duplicate. Why would you consider that as not a duplicate?

Comment: @jpp Added one more Q&A that's solves exclusively to make the numbers 0...n, so again that offsetting of `1` is needed.

Comment: @jpp That's why only the first half of the accepted answer of the first Q&A that involves using `np.unique(..., return_inverse=True)` is to be used. Hence, added that second Q&A that directly plugs into this question. What do you say about that second linked Q&A?

Comment: @Divakar, looks good now (seems like I was looking at an old version of that post). & upvoted. I will also add my answer there.

Comment: I don't follow the discussion, but I see the answer seems to be known even though there is still no actual answer posted... Isn't `np.unique([4, 25, 100, 4, 50], return_inverse=True)[1] + 1` a valid solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a convenient method via `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

lst = [4, 25, 100, 4, 50]
res = pd.factorize(lst, sort=True)[0] + 1

# [1 2 4 1 3]
```